# IdentityServer 4 - How to logout of all MVC apps?

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer 4. I have a setup very similar to the asp.net Identity quickstart as on the IdentityServer documentation [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html) .

I want to be able enable a single logout from the IdentityServer web application, so that when I call this POST method, it logs out from all of the connected applications.

I have an IdentityServer web application, and an MVC web application which uses Asp.net identity mediated by the IdentityServer application.

What's happening with the default setup (as per the quickstart) is that when you logout from within the IdentityServer app, if you've already logged in on the MVC web application, you will remain logged in on the MVC web application until the MVC cookie has expired.

Is there a way of adapting the quickstart so that you have a centralized sign-out method within the IdentityServer application that you can call from anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP based logout add a [logoutUri](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/client.html#authentication-logout) to each of your clients and http://localhost:5000/account/logout should do that. You'll see an iframe with the endsession url which contains an iframe for each logoutUri that you've logged into for that session (stored in the cookie)

see: 
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html

Make sure your [account controller](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs) and [logged out view](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Views/Account/LoggedOut.cshtml) match the quickstart samples.